# How to get $D^\mu S D_\mu S=0$ from the wave equation

Tags: black-holes, qft-in-curved-spacetime

I am reading with the paper [Introduction to Black Hole Evaporation](https://arxiv.org/abs/1310.8312) by Pierre-Henry Lambert.

In chapter 3.3, considering $f=ae^{iS}$ and the wave equation, equation $(3.10)$ says:

$$0=D_\mu D^\mu (ae^{iS})=D_\mu((D^\mu a)e^{iS}+ia(D^\mu S)e^{iS})=\\=(D_\mu D^\mu a)e^{iS}+2i(D^\mu a)(D_\mu S)e^{iS}+ia(D_\mu D^\mu S) e^{iS}-aD^\mu S D_\mu S e^{iS}=0$$

We are assuming the amplitude to vary slowing so we can neglect the first two terms. In particular, the author is also neglecting the third term, making a double integration.
Now, from the double integration I got:
$i(D^\mu D_\mu S)f=iS D^\mu D_\mu f-i[SD_\mu f]+i[D^\mu Sf]$
where the last two terms are computed at the boundary.

I don't see how can one neglect the second term of the latter equation in order to get then the final equation $D^\mu S D_\mu S=0$

Thanks!

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v1): In the future please link to abstract pages rather than pdf files, e.g., http://arxiv.org/abs/1310.8312

Comment: The phase is assumed to be quickly varying. We can write $S = \alpha \tilde{S}$ where $\alpha \gg 1$. We then keep only the order-$\alpha^2$ terms in our equation, since these are largest.

Comment: @gj255, so, are you assuming the derivative of S to be a large quantity or S itself?Furthermore, why is the author simply writing $i(D^\mu D_\mu S)f=iS D^\mu D_\mu f$ without considering the boundary terms ? Wouldn't they be of the same order of $iS D^\mu D_\mu f$?

Comment: I'm assuming that $S$ and its derivative are of the same order, $\alpha$. I then neglect the 'second term of the latter equation' because it is order-$\alpha$, not $\alpha^2$. I don't know exactly how Lambert is trying to derive this result, but at first glance it looks wrong, since there are no integrals with which to 'integrate by parts'! However, with regards your concern of dropping boundary terms, this will be legitimate provided the function $f$ is localised (which will be true, for example, if we work with wavepackets instead of pure plane waves).

Comment: @gj255 thank you! So, just to summarize: from $i(D_\mu D^\mu S) e^{iS}-D^\mu S D_\mu S e^{iS}=0$ assuming the phase to be really large, we can express this writing $S= \alpha \tilde{S} $ where $\alpha \gg 1$; hence $i\alpha (D_\mu D^\mu S) e^{i\alpha S}-\alpha^2 D^\mu S D_\mu S e^{i\alpha S}=0$ since $\alpha \gg 1 $ we can keep the order $\alpha ^2$ since it is the largest. Hence we get $D_\mu S D^\mu S=0$. Is this what you meant, right?

Comment: Exactly, that's right.